# Using FindRoot to find a Parameter

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

Let's say I have the typical harmonic oscillator ODE

```
system = {x''[t] + x[t] == 0,
          x[0] == 1,
          x'[0] == Vi};
```

with undetermined initial velocity $V_i$ and I solve it with `NDSolve` in the following way

```
solut[p1_] := NDSolve[system /. {Vi -> p1}, {x}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Now I want to know how the final velocity $x'(10)$ depends on the initial velocity $V_i$, so I do

```
Plot[x'[10] /. solut[p1][[1]], {p1, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"Vi", "x'(10)"}]
```

[image]

Eventually I want to find the root of this function, which as you can see from the figure is approximately at $V_i\approx 0.65$. How can I do it?
If I try with `FindRoot` it doesn't work; explicitly what i get is

```
FindRoot[x'[10] /. solut[p1][[1]], {p1, 0.5}]
(*NDSolve: Initial condition p1 is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers.*)
```

and other errors.
Thank you very much for helping.

NOTE: This is not my actual problem, but a very simplified version of it. I solved a similar problem by treating $V_i$ as a parameter using `ParametricNDSolve`, but this time I'd like to avoid it and use `NDSolve` and `FindRoot` only, if possible.

Comment: Can you expand on why you want to avoid `ParametricNDSolve`? That did seem a more natural avenue of attack for this problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it very easily with `ParametricNDSolveValue`:

```
system = {x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == Vi}
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[system, x'[10], {t, 0, 10}, {Vi}]
FindRoot[sol[vi], {vi, 0.5}]
```

> {vi -> 0.648361}

If you really insist on not using `ParametricNDSolveValue`:

```
system2[Vi_] := {x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == Vi};
sol2[Vi_?NumericQ] := NDSolveValue[system2[Vi], x'[10], {t, 0, 10}]
FindRoot[sol2[vi], {vi, 0.3, 0.5}] (* Use two initial guesses for the tangent minimization method *)
```

> {vi -> 0.648361}

But only do the latter if the former really doesn't work since the FindRoot will be more effective if it can use gradient information from `ParametricNDSolveValue`.

Comment: (+1) A difference that might be worth mentioning is that since `sol'[vi]` is defined, `FindRoot` will use Newton's method in the `ParametricNDSolve` case.

Answer (score 3):

With a parameter use [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

system = {x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == Vi};
```

For comparison, the exact solution is

```
solution[Vi_, t_] = DSolve[system, x, t][[1]]

(* {x -> Function[{t}, Cos[t] + Vi Sin[t]]} *)
```

Verifying the exact solution

```
system /. solution[Vi, t]

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

The numeric solution is

```
solution2 = ParametricNDSolve[system, x, {t, 0, 10}, {Vi}]
```

[image]

Verifying that the numeric solutions agree with the exact solutions:

```
Show[
 Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /.
    Table[solution[Vi, t], {Vi, 0, 10, 5}]], {t, 0, 10}],
 Plot[Evaluate[
   Table[x[Vi][t] /. solution2, {Vi, 0, 10, 5}]], {t, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dotted]]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
Plot[Derivative[1][x[Vi]][10] /. solution2, {Vi, -1, 1},
 AxesLabel -> {Vi, HoldForm[x'[10]]}]
```

[image]

```
FindRoot[(Derivative[1][x[Vi]][10] /. solution2) == 0, {Vi, 0.6}]

(* {Vi -> 0.648361} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
X = DSolveValue[system , x, {t, 0, 10}]
X'[10] (*Vi Cos[10] - Sin[10]*)
```